# PostgreSQL group by error

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a relation in a PostgreSQL database called 'processed_data' having the following schema:

Date -> date type, shop_id -> integer type, item_category_id -> integer type, sum_item_cnt_day -> real type.

Displaying the first 5 rows of the relation is as follows:

```
date  |  shop_id  |  item_category_id  |  sum_item_cnt_day

------+-----------+--------------------+------------------

2014-12-29  |  49  |  3  |  4

2014-12-29  |  49  |  6  |  1

2014-12-29  |  49  |  7  |  1

2014-12-29  |  49  |  12  |  3

2014-12-29  |  49  |  16  |  1
```

Now, the 'shop_id' has 60 unique shops ranging from 0-59 where each shop sells some items grouped to a new column 'item_category_id' where 'sum_item_cnt_day' denotes the number of items sold by a shop and it's item_category_id.

I am now trying to further aggregate the data by just trying to get the following columns as final result-

date, shop_id, sum_item_cnt_day

So that, data is aggregated according to number of all items sold in 'item_category_id' per shop (denoted by 'shop_id') and calculating sum of 'sum_item_cnt_day'.

When I try to execute the following SQL command-

```
select date, shop_id, sum(sum_item_cnt_day) from processed_data group by shop_id;
```

It gives the error-

ERROR:  column "processed_data.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select date, shop_id, sum(sum_item_cnt_day) from processed_d...
               ^

Even the following SQL command-

```
select date, shop_id, sum(sum_item_cnt_day) from processed_data where date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' group by shop_id;
```

Gives the error-

ERROR:  column "processed_data.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select date, shop_id, sum(sum_item_cnt_day) from processed_d...
               ^

Any suggestions as to what's going wrong and what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix, which is what I think you want, would be to just add `date` to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT date, shop_id, SUM(sum_item_cnt_day)
FROM processed_data
GROUP BY date, shop_id;
```

If you really don't want sums taken for each shop on each day, but rather for each shop over *all* days, then you will have to think of which of the many dates you want to display.

Comment: Is there a way to group data for the relation such that 'sum_item_cnt_day' is summed in a date wise manner for each unique/distinct combination of 'shop_id' and 'item_category_id' ?

Comment: @Arun Maybe, I'd have to see data to know what you have in mind.  But, this is a departure from your current question, so I would suggest that you open a new one.

Comment: I am trying to fit different machine learning and deep learning models pertaining to time series analysis and forecasting so I know how to shape data for the models. I will open a new question.